# How I can increase Java Heap Space for Cygnus?

Tags: java, fiware, fiware-cygnus

Good afternoon!

For days, my cygnus agent has returned the following log that I have attached, how could I increase the memory assigned to Java for this process?
Thank you very much to all!

```
time=2018-03-16T12:02:53.282Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=05e3c64e-2908-11e8-8967-fa163e33d403 | trans=b8f80c9f-b321-4d6b-bfd6-2e846cc2fd7c | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:02:19.216Z | lvl=INFO | corr=1492a660-2908-11e8-a3e9-fa163e33d403 | trans=a5a375f2-23f1-4d52-b86e-036b066b2306 | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[286] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (a5a375f2-23f1-4d52-b86e-036b066b2306)
time=2018-03-16T12:02:19.038Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=05498d04-2908-11e8-91c3-fa163e33d403 | trans=79acff3b-af66-4a30-ba0a-6f2d1702c50f | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:02:12.637Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=02148a58-2908-11e8-83b6-fa163e33d403 | trans=68772803-ae98-481e-844c-26fef99c33cb | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:02:12.458Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=06708caa-2908-11e8-ba44-fa163e33d403 | trans=8e9d7e35-82d4-4b1c-9ad9-49c67d0172a1 | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:02:12.281Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=076b4b7c-2908-11e8-9150-fa163e33d403 | trans=67284db2-9814-4d22-8238-d8258d05581b | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:02:07.557Z | lvl=INFO | corr=14519116-2908-11e8-a7ac-fa163e33d403 | trans=621e2e69-d244-4ef9-930e-c70e8b9fd7ca | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[286] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (621e2e69-d244-4ef9-930e-c70e8b9fd7ca)
time=2018-03-16T12:02:07.380Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=13a7f7b4-2908-11e8-b59b-fa163e33d403 | trans=8bfe2de9-d681-44f5-9847-24a5388ee6bf | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:01:54.904Z | lvl=INFO | corr=12c9a0ae-2908-11e8-9994-fa163e33d403 | trans=ed8ea56a-3d5b-4511-aefd-12443f38301e | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[286] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (ed8ea56a-3d5b-4511-aefd-12443f38301e)
time=2018-03-16T12:01:54.724Z | lvl=INFO | corr=123b73e2-2908-11e8-948c-fa163e33d403 | trans=c4fbff8e-5a3f-402d-831b-2c27ab5caa53 | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[286] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (c4fbff8e-5a3f-402d-831b-2c27ab5caa53)
time=2018-03-16T12:01:54.601Z | lvl=INFO | corr=11e01416-2908-11e8-b801-fa163e33d403 | trans=7b1b4ef0-2fb1-4c4f-b18f-c807d6ad696c | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[286] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (7b1b4ef0-2fb1-4c4f-b18f-c807d6ad696c)
time=2018-03-16T12:01:54.601Z | lvl=INFO | corr=11a0e28c-2908-11e8-aae7-fa163e33d403 | trans=17ff5f1a-08a6-4ce2-8993-893e055e99d8 | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[286] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (17ff5f1a-08a6-4ce2-8993-893e055e99d8)
time=2018-03-16T12:01:54.601Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=11614b40-2908-11e8-831d-fa163e33d403 | trans=d0c68e25-4e53-4557-9eb5-2a3d5f6b5407 | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:01:38.801Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=099ffaa0-2908-11e8-bfd9-fa163e33d403 | trans=d0225044-f783-4570-923b-bf519d9615fc | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:01:38.563Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=091bcd70-2908-11e8-832a-fa163e33d403 | trans=e645e877-a131-4075-9372-f4553bb9ce25 | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:01:38.324Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=0a50cd3a-2908-11e8-82ae-fa163e33d403 | trans=231ec951-9da8-4a52-81de-65cdbc57e98e | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
time=2018-03-16T12:01:38.081Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=0abdb2e2-2908-11e8-8b29-fa163e33d403 | trans=fac8385f-79fa-464a-9b62-0e035c3f9c54 | srv=default | subsrv=/sevilla | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : Error for /notify
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: I don't know Cygnus, do you know how the Java process is started? Somewhere around that there's normally an option for the heap size, which in the end is passed as a parameter to the `java` call.

Answer (score 3):

You can find in the official [Cygnus Documentation how to configure Flume env variables in where you can increase your JAVA Heap size](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/flume_env_conf/index.html) . Also you can use this command `$ export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"` where the 512m indicates the amount of memory in megabytes that you want to manage, but doing that you set the heap size globally, it means that you set that value for all the applications.

Another option is using this command `java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx6144m pathToJarFile.jar` and replace `pathToJarFile.jar` with the path in where your cygnus jar was installed.

If you want to learn more about the Java heap size in [this link are some summarized information about it](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control).

Best Regards,